# Stock product and lot duplicate finder

Tags: python, odoo

I have this function that searches for stock moves that have the same product, and if it finds them then it searches for lots in those lines, and if it finds the same lots then UserError is raised.

The thing is I think this method can be rewritten in a more elegant way. Maybe someone can help me with that.

```
def check_for_duplicates(self):
    exist_product_list = {}
    duplicates = {}
    for line in picking.move_lines:
        if line.product_id.id in exist_product_list:
            duplicates[line.id] = line.product_id.id
            for product, line_id in exist_product_list.items():
                if product == line.product_id.id and line.id != line_id:
                    duplicates[line.id] = line.product_id.id
                    duplicates[line_id] = product
        exist_product_list[line.product_id.id] = line.id
    duplicate_lots = []
    if duplicates:
        for line in self.env['stock.move'].browse(duplicates.keys()):
            lots = line.mapped('lot_ids')
            for lot in lots:
                if lot in duplicate_lots:
                    raise UserError(
                        _('You have few lines with same product %s and same lot in it') % line.product_id.name)
                duplicate_lots.append(lot)
```

Comment: The current question title of your question is too generic to be helpful. Please edit to the site standard, which is for the title to simply **state the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://CodeReview.StackExchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: where is `picking` coming from?

Comment: @hjpotter92 i missed here one line. For picking in self:. so the picking coming from self

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Avoid similar variable names

There's `line.product_id.id`, `line_id` and `line.id`. This is very confusing. Try to avoid having variable names that are too close to each other.

## Simplifying the code

You can indeed simplify the code somewhat. First, you want to find out if there are multiple lines that reference the same product. To do that, you want to have a `dict` that maps from product IDs to a list of lines. The easiest way to do this is to use a `defaultdict(list)`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def check_for_duplicates(self):
    product_lines = defaultdict(list)

    # Build a map of which lines reference which products
    for line in picking.move_lines:
        product_lines[line.product_id.id].append(line.id)
```

Then you can go over that map to check if any product occurs on more than one line:

```
    # Find duplicates
    for product, lines in product_lines.items():
        if len(lines) > 1:
            # Report lines with duplicate products here
            ...
```

I'm not sure how to improve on the part that checks for duplicate lots, I don't know what type `self.env[...]` is and what the `browse()` function does, but perhaps the above code will help you simplify that as well.